# Automatically convert video podcasts to "ipod or iphone version"

Tags: itunes, video, ipod, podcasts

I'm downloading a regular video podcast for use on my ipod.

I like that the podcasts download automatically, but the problem is that I have to manually select all the videos I want to sync and then select "Create an iPod or iPhone version" from the advanced menu in iTunes.

This is a real pain, and if I forget even one video then iTunes comes up with a message saying that 100+ videos aren't in the right format for the sync to work (if they were converted they sync fine though).

Is there any way to get iTunes to do this conversion automatically once the download is finished, so then whenever I sync my iPod the videos will be synced automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, iTunes just won't do this.  :(